# Compare vector<int> for almost equal, STL Algorithm - C++

Tags: c++, vector, compare, equals

Im doing an task atm. which I should compare all of the vector elements in an given range, in two different vector, for almost equal with help of STL algorithm.

Almost equal in this situation: 2.

Anyone know an solution for this problem?

Comment: Is this some sort of homework or not?

Comment: So if two ints are within 2 of each other, they are almost equal? So 10 and 12 are almost equal in your task?

Comment: So you want a single result, `true` if *all* are almost equal and `false` if any are not, or do you want a `std::vector<bool>` of results? Please edit your question to elaborate.

Comment: Do the vectors have to have the same number of elements to be 'almost equal'? For example, would `{0, 2}` and `{1}` be almost equal?

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: yeah single result.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Yeah, at least the given range would have the same number.

Comment: I'd give some example code of what you've tried... This will GREATLY help explain what you're trying to do...

Comment: -1 for being so vague.  Please clean up your question.

Comment: There's a little text link below your question that says 'edit'.  Click it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want less-than comparison, use [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) with a custom comparator implementing whatever it is that almost equal means for you.

If you want equality comparison, use [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal), as pointed out in the comments:

```
bool comp(int a, int b) {
  return std::abs(a-b) <= 2;
}

int main() {

  std::vector<int> v0{2,3,4,5,5,5};
  std::vector<int> v1{6,7,8,9,8,7};
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << std::equal(v0.begin(), v0.end(), v1.begin(), comp);

}
```

This is a simplified comparison function to show how to use the algorithm, you would have to decide what to do if the vectors have different length.

Comment: @chris good point, but it depends on what behaviour OP wants, which I must admit I haven't figured out...

Comment: @chris: Yeah I have looked abit at std::equal, but im not quite sure about the parts I have seen there..

Comment: @AndersKvisvik I added an example, although it is difficult to know what exactly you need.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I thought the spec required the predicate to be transitive, but neither the spec nor MSDN docs say that, so comment retracted.  `std::equal` should work.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think transitive comparisons are only needed for imposing an ordering on a range of values, which we aren't doing here.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [g19fanatic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287052/845092):

```
template<class iterator1, class iterator2>
bool almostEqual(iterator1 begin1, iterator1 end1, 
                 iterator2 begin2, iterator2 end2, int tolerance)
{
    for(;begin1!=end1; ++begin1, ++begin2) {
        if (begin2 == end2)
            return false;
        if (*begin1 - tolerance > *begin2)
            return false;
        if (*begin1 + tolerance < *begin2)
            return false;
    }
    if (begin2 != end2)
        return false;
    return true;
}

template<class container1, class container2>
bool almostEqual(container1 left, container2 right, int tolerance)
{ 
    return almostEqual(left.begin(), left.end(), 
                       right.begin(), right.end(), tolerance);
}
```

Proof of compilation/execution: http://ideone.com/y6jBR

Comment: +1 for taking my crude (put as much effort into it as he did asking it) answer and providing a better one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "math.h"
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> vec1,vec2;
std::vector<bool> resVec;

void almostEqual(std::vector<int> vec1,std::vector<int> vec2,std::vector<bool>& resVec, int tolerance)
{
    resVec.clear();
    if (vec1.size() != vec2.size()) {return;}

    std::vector<int>::iterator it;

    int i = 0;
    for (it = vec1.begin(); it != vec1.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (abs(*it - vec2[i++]) <= abs(tolerance))
        {
            resVec.push_back(true);
        } else {
            resVec.push_back(false);
        }
    }
}
```

based off of the very little we have, this is what i'd do....

Answer (score 0):

The standard library function [`inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) iterates over two containers, performing some operation for each pair, and accumulates the result. So we can use this to compare whether each pair is within 2, and accumulate that all comparisons are true.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool all(bool first, bool second)
{
  return first && second;
}

bool within_two(int first, int second)
{
  return abs(first - second) <= 2;
}

int main()
{
  using std::vector;
  using std::inner_product;
  using std::boolalpha;
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  vector<int> first = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  vector<int> second = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

  bool almost_equal = inner_product(first.begin(), first.end(),
                                    second.begin(),
                                    true,
                                    all, within_two);

  cout << "almost_equal=" << boolalpha << almost_equal << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
almost_equal=true
```

Comment: I never knew about `inner_product`. neat!

Comment: It is neat, although the `std::equals` answer is simpler in this case. When formulating uses for it, it makes me think of [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), although it isn't exactly that.